# Android Development: "thread exiting with uncaught exception"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my first Android App (a game) but I'm having some difficulties getting started.

When I run my code I get this error log:

```
05-25 02:41:51.022: WARN/dalvikvm(634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stickfigs.nmg/com.stickfigs.nmg.NMG}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at com.stickfigs.nmg.NMG.onCreate(NMG.java:32)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-25 02:41:51.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     ... 11 more
05-25 02:41:51.062: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.stickfigs.nmg/.NMG
```

I think the problem is this "thread exiting with uncaught exception" part, I have no idea what the exception could be or what's causing it.

Here is my code:

**NMGView.java:**
    package com.stickfigs.NMG;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

class NMGView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    class NMGThread extends Thread {
        //State-tracking constants
        public static final int STATE_LOSE = 1;
        public static final int STATE_PAUSE = 2;
        public static final int STATE_READY = 3;
        public static final int STATE_RUNNING = 4;
        public static final int STATE_WIN = 5;

        /** The state of the game. One of READY, RUNNING, PAUSE, LOSE, or WIN */
        private int mode;

        /** Handle to the surface manager object we interact with */
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

        public NMGThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolderc, Context contextc) {
            // get handles to some important objects
            surfaceHolder = surfaceHolderc;
            context = contextc;

        }

        /**
         * Restores game state from the indicated Bundle. Typically called when
         * the Activity is being restored after having been previously
         * destroyed.
         * 
         * @param savedState Bundle containing the game state
         */
        public synchronized void restoreState(Bundle savedState) {
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                setState(STATE_PAUSE);
                }
        }

        /**
         * Sets the game mode. That is, whether we are running, paused, in the
         * failure state, in the victory state, etc.
         * 
         * @param mode one of the STATE_* constants
         * @param message string to add to screen or null
         */
        public void setState(int modec) {
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                mode = modec;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /** Handle to the application context, used to e.g. fetch Drawables. */
    private Context context;

    /** The thread that actually draws the animation */
    private NMGThread thread;

    public NMGView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
        thread = new NMGThread(holder, context);

        setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the animation thread corresponding to this LunarView.
     * 
     * @return the animation thread
     */
    public NMGThread getThread() {
        return thread;
    }
}
```

**NMG.java:**

```
package com.stickfigs.nmg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;

import com.stickfigs.nmg.NMGView.NMGThread;

public class NMG extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    /** A handle to the thread that's actually running the animation. */
    private NMGThread nMGThread;

    /** A handle to the View in which the game is running. */
    private NMGView nMGView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Turn off the window's title bar
        // TODO Turn off the status bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // tell system to use the layout defined in our XML file
        setContentView(R.layout.nmg_layout);

        // get handles to the LunarView from XML, and its LunarThread
        nMGView = (NMGView) findViewById(R.id.nmg);
        nMGThread = nMGView.getThread();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // we were just launched: set up a new game
            nMGThread.setState(NMGThread.STATE_READY);
            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "SIS is null");
        } else {
            // we are being restored: resume a previous game
            nMGThread.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "SIS is nonnull");
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here is my R.java and nmg_layout.xml:

**R.java:**
    package com.stickfigs.nmg;

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int nmg=0x7f050000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int nmg_layout=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

**nmg_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.stickfigs.nmg.NMGView
      android:id="@+id/nmg"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: hey can you tell me how did you solve this error exactlly, because i am getting the same kinda error, and when i comment the line  mentioned in the logcat, it points out to different line. its kinda strange ???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look through the stack trace, you will see a "Caused by..." line (sometimes more than one). The last one of those is the important one. It says that there was a null pointer exception on line 32 of NMG.java. That line, and the line before it, are:

```
nMGView = (NMGView) findViewById(R.id.nmg);
nMGThread = nMGView.getThread();
```

Evidently, no view with id `R.id.nmg` is in layout `R.layout.nmg_layout`. That's what's causing your problem.

Comment: That's strange because it does exist in the layout file and in R. I added both to my original question.

Comment: Hm. Perhaps I counted lines wrong? If not, I suggest adding the line `assert nMGView != null;` in between those two lines. See if that causes your app to crash due to a failed assert instead of a NPE.

Comment: Tried that and it still fails for the same reason as before.

Comment: Still a NPE on line 32? Can you verify that I counted lines correctly? Or else point to exactly which line is generating the exception.

Comment: So, to verify: the line `nMGThread = nMGView.getThread();` generates a NullPointerException and yet `nMGView` is definitely **not** `null`. Can you confirm via debugger?

Comment: Hmm hold on actually the debugger says nMGView **is** null

Comment: Well, now the question is, why is nMGView null? First thing is to clean and rebuild your project, to make sure Eclipse isn't getting confused about something.

Comment: Glad it's working. For future reference, clean the project by selecting Project > Clean... from the Eclipse menu.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the obvious text that was there. It made me read it and solve my problem !

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file, the `R.id.nmg` do exist.
So I think the problem is caused by inflating the `NMGView` object from the resource.
You should examine your `NMGView` source code, especially in its constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure what inflating means. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If the problem were caused by instantiating NMGView while inflating nmg_layout, the exception would be generated by the call to `setContentView`. The exception is coming later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "**multiDexEnabled true**" in your "**build.gradle(Module:app)**"  , remove this line from "**defaultConfig**" and sync project.
It works in my case !!!

Answer (score 0):

This problems happens because most of the time the SurfaceView onDraw() method is running when you destroy the surfaceView then you get a NULL POINTER ERROR because the canvas doesn´t exist by that moment. I have fixed this problem catching  all the drawing stuff  with the NullPointerException:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    try {
         //Drawing Stuff

   }catch(NullPointerException e){
        Log.e("NULL POINTER EXCEPTION","Canvas NULL POINTER");
    }
}
```

If you implement onPause(), onDestroy() methods in your Main activity you will get the following order: first: E/onPause﹕ ON PAUSE --> next E/surfaceDestroyed﹕ SURFACE DESTROYED --> E/NULL POINTER EXCEPTION﹕ Canvas NULL POINTER --> finally
E/onDestroy﹕ ON DESTROY

this is surfaceDestroyed method I am using:

```
   @Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    Log.e("surfaceDestroyed", "SURFACE DESTROYED ");


    thread.setRunning(false);
        try {
            //thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           Log.e("Surface Thread Stopped","SURFACE THREAD STOPPED");
        }

}
```